# Chrome, IE8 doesn't show jquery html text - Synch Ajax. it works in Firefox

Tags: jquery

In js (jquery 1.7) I use this code: When clicking on button two actions are supposed to happen: 1. show status (show html) 2. run function to generate pdf

```
$( "#create_box" ).on("click", "#make_pdf_btn",function(){
$('.pdf_status0').html('Generating report...' );  // problematic line
 make_pdf2();
 return false;
  });
```

then:

```
function make_pdf2(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "make_pdf.php",   // pdf is created and saved
            async: false,          // synchronous  ajax
            success: function(html){ strReturn = html; }
    });

   if ( strReturn == 'pdfok' ){ 
        $('.pdf_status0').html('Done!<br>');
        $('.pdf_status').show();
       } else {
         $('.pdf_status').html('Error creating pdf.' );  
       }
  return false;
```

}

Problem is that line $('.pdf_status0').html('Generating report...' ); is running ok in firefox and text 'Generating report ...' is shown in div, then it is replaced with 'Done!'. 
However Chrome and IE8 don't show 'Generating report..' only 'Done!' and pdf is created.

if i use alert('text') instead of jquery html it is run and alert is shown in ie, chrome and firefox

Comment: Does your Ajax call need to be _synchronous?_ That'll be the problem. Does it work if you refactor your code with `async:true`, with the second half of `make_pdf2()` moved into the ajax success function?

Comment: yes, i want it to by synchronous - due to response text...

Comment: What response text? If you mean the "Done" message that can be moved into the success callback.

Comment: i mean strReturn == 'pdfok' from php script. i think it works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a synchronous ajax call it usually locks up the browser until the response is processed, which means the screen isn't repainted to show your "Generating report..." message until after it's too late because you've already changed it to "Done!".

There's almost never a good reason to use synchronous ajax, and I can't see anything in your code that can't be easily refactored to be asynchronous - which gives the browser a chance to repaint while the ajax call is in progress:

```
function make_pdf2(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "make_pdf.php",   // pdf is created and saved
            async: true,          // use Asynchronous  ajax
            success: function(html){
               // do all required processing on response in the success callback
               strReturn = html;
               if ( strReturn == 'pdfok' ){ 
                  $('.pdf_status0').html('Done!<br>');
                  $('.pdf_status').show();
               } else {
                  $('.pdf_status').html('Error creating pdf.' );  
              }
           }
    });

  return false;      
}
```

Having said that, I've occasionally that found older IE (not sure about IE8) still gets a bit confused in a way that can be fixed with a `setTimeout()` hack:

```
setTimeout(make_pdf2, 4); // make call to make_pdf2() async too
```

Comment: usually - but not in Firefox: i will probably try to make it async - what i want to do is to wait until pdf is created on server side. ( i use pdf library html2pdf )

Comment: this is what i'm looking for - when pdf is created it echoes 'pdfok' then in front u get 'Done!' message. If there is something wrong different text is sent to front so u get 'Error creating pdf.' message. for some reason i thought it has to by synchronous to get correct text  from php..

Comment: Async is fine. The success function gets called once a response is received, so you can do your processing there.

Comment: this will not work ( with async:true ), but you can use 'done': `.done(function( strReturn ) { if ( strReturn == 'copyok' ) {` with async: true

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be this way:

```
$(function(){
   $( "#create_box" ).on("click", "#make_pdf_btn",function(){
     $('.pdf_status0').html('Generating report...').promise().done(function(){
        make_pdf2();
     });
     return false;
   });
});

function make_pdf2(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "make_pdf.php",   // pdf is created and saved
        async: false,          // synchronous  ajax
        success: function(html){ 
             strReturn = html;
             if ( strReturn == 'pdfok' ){ 
                  $('.pdf_status0').html('Done!<br>');
                  $('.pdf_status').show();
             } else {
                  $('.pdf_status').html('Error creating pdf.' );  
             } 
        }
   });      
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does the same: 'Generating report' shows in firefox (v.16) but chrome and ie dont show this html. basicaly function make_pdf2() freezes browser. but i assume if the line is first it would show, then it goes to next line: makepdf2() function.
Likely i'd have to make it synchronous..